# Symbol for red dot in a circle inside an inverted triangle

Tags: symbols, color, tikzsymbols

I have a lot of data points that have been plotted in graphs saved as `.png`. I am making a table of these points with symbol as one of the columns.

Using the `tikz` package, I am able to obtain a red dot inscribed in a blue circle but I am unable to superscribe a down triangle on it. 
The incomplete triangle appears beside it.

The code I have written is as follows.

```
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\bluetrireddot}[1][0.3]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=#1]
\draw[fill=red,red] (0,0) circle (0.15);
\draw[blue] (0,0) circle (0.35);
\draw[green] (0,1) -- (1,0) -- (2,1);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
```

The output is as shown.

[image]

What I want is something like this (this image is from the graph):

[image]

Comment: Replace your green path by `\draw[green] (-90:.77) -- (30:.77) -- (150:.77)--cycle;`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think that this is a situation where the `pic` thingy might make sense.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{blueredgreen/.pic={%
\fill[red] (0,0) circle (0.15);
\draw[thick,green!60!black] (30:0.5) -- (150:0.5) -- (270:0.5) -- cycle;  
\draw[thick,blue] (0,0) circle (0.25);}
}
\newcommand{\bluetrireddot}[1][0.3]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pic[scale=#1] {blueredgreen};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
\begin{document}
Hello \bluetrireddot symbol!
\end{document}
```

[image]

BTW, there are dedicated libraries for `pgfplotmarks`, see p. 678 of the pgfmanual (not pgfplots manual!), which you may also consider.

Comment: I don't understand what the point of the pic is...?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi As explained in the pgfmanual on p. 251:
A “pic” is a “short picture” (hence the short name...) . And one of the points is that, if the user ever decides to use the symbol inside a Ti*k*Z picture, then there is a simple syntax that allows her/him to use it *without* nesting Ti*k*Z pictures.

Answer (score 8):

You could use a triangular node from the `shapes` library.

Edit: I incorporated the rotation, but also changed the command to scale properly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\newcommand{\bluetrireddot}[1][0.5]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node(t)[green,regular polygon,regular polygon sides=3,rotate=180,draw,scale=#1] at (0,0){};
\node at (t.center)[circle,fill=red,scale=0.5*#1]{};
\node at (t.center)[circle,blue,draw,scale=#1]{};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}
\dots images \bluetrireddot\ acquired \dots
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You can also use `rotate=180` in the node options to flip it upside down.

Comment: Thanks @ichbinallen, I completely overlooked the orientation of the triangle!