# what can I do if I want a symbol "a triangle with a centered dot inside it" and other symbols in the latex?

Tags: symbols

I want symbols "a triangle with a centered dot inside it", "a triangle with a circle inside it", "a downtriangle with a centered dot inside it", and also "a downtriangle with a circle inside it". I have tried the package stix and then type the command "\trianglecdot" in the source file. It can give me the first symbol, but this package stix is not good, since in the meanwhile it can also make the style of many other symbols not good-looking. For the remaining three symbols, I do not find suitable packages and commands either.

How to expose all the four symbols? Many thanks.

Comment: It's not necessary to load an entire symbol font if only a few symbols are needed.  Here's a question that covers that situation: [Importing a single symbol from a different font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14386)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

thanks to member `erik`

have a look here -- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/429103/197451

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\newcommand{\bluetrireddot}[1][0.5]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node(t)[green,regular polygon,regular polygon sides=3,rotate=180,draw,scale=#1] at 
 (0,0){};
\node at (t.center)[circle,fill=red,scale=0.5*#1]{};
\node at (t.center)[circle,blue,draw,scale=#1]{};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}
\dots images \bluetrireddot\ acquired \dots
\end{document}
```

Comment: This helps a lot, I got it! Thank you so much!

Comment: you may like to upvote and accept the answer

Answer (score 1):

`\tdotcircle` work only inline mode and not like underscript o overscript mode.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\newcommand{\upodot}[1][0pt]{%
  \mathrel{\raisebox{#1}{$\odot$}}%
}
\newcommand{\tdotcircle}{\mathrlap{\mkern8.5mu\scaleobj{.55}{\upodot[2.1pt]}}\triangledown}
\begin{document}

\[a\tdotcircle b\]
\end{document}
```

[image]